# Simulation and calculus of magnetic force in orthodontics

Tags: simulation, calculator

I need to calculate the magnetic force and run simulation applied to orthodontics. I'm looking for a simulation and calulation software.

Suppose that we have to calculate the magnetic force related to this scenario: [image: this].

I think that the order of magnitude should be arount 50-250 mTesla.

Are there any software/library that allow me to run this experimentation?
Thanks.

It can be done in every language and OS platform. No specific requirement here. Thanks you

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What OS must it run on (or in case of a library, what programming language it must fit)? Must it be [tag:gratis] – or what amount of money you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions?

Comment: It can be done in every language and OS platform. No specific requirement here. Thanks you

Comment: Thanks Mark! And what about the price tag?